# Need to hide Future months in Materialize Date Picker for current year. When I change year from picker then all month should appear

Tags: datepicker, materialize

I need help for the Materialize Date Picker. I want to show only current month in current Year in DatePicker Select dropdown. and when I change the previous Year, all months should be shown. I have achieved that for the current year only showing till current month but rest future months shows undefined. However, If I am changing the previous year from datepicker year dropdown, All Months are not showing. I think I need to apply the function with change event. But I am not understanding how I''ll call it in Materialize Picker.
Here is my Code..

I will really appreciate if anyone please help me where I am making mistake in below code. I am not professional in it.

```
    <html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s3">
            <input type="text" class="datepicker">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var today = new Date();
        var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
        var currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();
        var yyRange = [2018];
            yyRange.push(currentYear);

        var currentSelectedYear = currentYear;
        var totalMonths = 11;
        if (currentSelectedYear == currentYear) {
            totalMonths = currentMonth;
        }
        var mmNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
        var mmRange = [];
        for (var i = 0; i <= totalMonths; i++) { mmRange.push(mmNames[i].toString()); }
        var options = {
            defaultDate: today,
            setDefaultDate: true,
            yearRange: yyRange,
            i18n: {
                months: mmRange,
            }
        };
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
        var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems, options);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried using `minDate` & `maxDate`?

Comment: No that is not working. If i will try maxDate: new Date(), then further dates will be disabled. However all months will be shown.